# Is there a way to keep a repeating alarm working after existing the app that uses a broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am new on Android. I am trying to create an application that uses `BroadcastReceiver` to execute a function on the main activity triggered by a repeating alarm. I read that I had to dynamically register the `broadcastReceiver` which I did - this is to be able to execute the function on the main activity. The problem I am faced with is that as soon as the app is exited, the `alarm` stops working. I read that this is by design - is there a way to overcome this or do I have to use a `service`? Thanks in advance.

Sample code:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {  
    @Override  
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
        Toast.makeText(context, "from AlarmReceiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;  
    private AlarmManager manager;  
    private AlarmReceiver myReceiver = null;  
    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
        myReceiver = new AlarmReceiver();  
        IntentFilter myIntentFilter = new IntentFilter("ANY_ACTION");  
        registerReceiver(myReceiver,  myIntentFilter);  
        Intent myIntent = new Intent();  
        myIntent.setAction("ANY_ACTION");  
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,myIntent,0);  
    }  
      public void startAlarm(View view) {  
        manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);  
        int interval = 1500;  
        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),   interval, pendingIntent);  
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    }     
}
```

Comment: Show your code, alarms work even when your app is not running. https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: Thanks Umarov, I added a sample code that shows my point  which is when the is app is existed the messages from the AlarmReceiver stops showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the reason why your alarm stops working when your app isn't running is that you're registering your *AlarmReceiver* locally with `registerReceiver`. If you want to  register your AlarmReceiver so that it keeps working even when your app isn't running, you need to register it inside `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Firstly, add your reciever into `AndroidManifest.xml` like this:

```
  <application>    
       //...
       <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
        </receiver>
       //...
  </application>
```

And set your alarm like this (Remember: Don't set alarm interval too short, set at least 1 minute; you set ur interval 1,5 second in ur code - it may not work):

```
    int interval = 60 * 1000;
    Intent intent=new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
```

And just do what you want to do when alarm triggers inside onRecieve:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Settings", 0);
    int iDefValue=0; 
    int iDayAlarmVal= sharedPreferences.getInt("something", iDefValue); 
    // and so on...
                 }
         }
```

Comment: Thanks again. If I do register it in the Manifest, the alarm will work, true - but as mentioned on the top I need to dynamically register it in order to be able to call a function defined in the Main-Activity.Where you mention "// ... do smth" is actually where I need to call the function that is defined on the main-activity.

Comment: what do you exactly want to do when alarm triggers?

Comment: To call a function defined in the main-activity i.e. the OnReceive (...) will have something like "myMain.DayExecute();" which defined in the main-activity.

Comment: I got it. Could you show your code inside DayExecute() function?

Comment: I'am asking for ur code because I think you might be able to perform your operation inside onReceive as well.

Comment: I actually started to think that I may have to define the function in the BroadcastReceiver and then call it from main-activity - this can resolve it.

Comment: I will put few lines of the code here so you can see them:  int iDefValue=0;        
        iDayAlarmVal= sharedPref.getInt(sDayAlarm,iDefValue);
  audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM,iDayAlarmVal,0);

Comment: sorry for breaking the comments, still new on this.

Comment: Could you please confirm that the Alarm stops when the app exist - did you simulate it

Comment: You can create instances of these calsses (SharedPreferences, AudioManager) using `context` argument that's being passed to onRecive.

Comment: I think it's impossbile to call MainActivity when your app isn't running, so perform ur operations inside onRecive method.

Comment: Thanks - can you please show me a sample of how they could be passed together in one call.

Comment: I think you didn't understand me.

Comment: I see what you mean now. It looks ok, I will try it and let you know.Thanks again.