# Android - Broadcast Receiver in Service, does not receive

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am using AlarmManager in order to set alarm.
I have a Service, and in that Service I have a Broadcast Receiver.

The problem is, when selected time and date comes, receiver cannot receive it.

onStart part of my Service class, and where is register my receiver:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onCreate();

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);

    Log.i("com.example.adama", "Service has started!");

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

onReceive Method for receiver:

```
    public static BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        Log.i("com.example.adama", "Receiver has received!"); ...}
```

Part that I run service and set alarm with AlarmManager:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, BrService.class);
    startService(serviceIntent);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BrService.class); 
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,alarmCode++, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.adama.wifiv2_spinner">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".BrService"/>
</application>
```

What am I missing?

I am trying this since I want receive it even user closes the app.

Comment: have you registered it in android menefiest file?

Comment: please show us your manifest file

Comment: I have added Manifest

Comment: If your `BroadcastReceiver` is not triggered then your `Service` may not be running.

Comment: I am starting service from MainActivity. In log, I can see that service is running. The problem is, the receiver in the Service is not receiving

Comment: What actually you service doing?

Comment: It runs always, and contains receiver, so receiver will be able to receive even user closes the app.

Comment: I found a thread that says in order for your receiver to run after exiting the app, the receiver needs to be registered in the manifest file. I updated my below answer to include the link. Try to register it there and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user force-close your app, there is nothing you can do to make your receiver run, other than the user restarting your app manually.

Other than that, please make sure that you added the BOOT_COMPLETED action to your intent filter, as well as the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission to your manifest, as described in this thread. This will let your receiver start up again after the phone has been rebooted (turned on and off again).

[Android BOOT_COMPLETED not received when application is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226410/android-boot-completed-not-received-when-application-is-closed)

Furthermore, on this thread it has been mentioned that in order for your receiver to work after the app has been closed (not force-closed), the receiver needs to be registered in the manifest:

[Is there a way to keep a repeating alarm working after existing the app that uses a broadcast receiver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060029/is-there-a-way-to-keep-a-repeating-alarm-working-after-existing-the-app-that-use?rq=1)

Give it a try and let us know if it helped you :)

Comment: Perfect :) Now, I have to find a way to set Alarms again after the phone restarted.

Comment: @Ege - Have a look at the boot_completed action and Receive_boot_completed permission as linked in the first part of the post :) Maybe store your alarms somewhere and reschedule them when you get the boot_completed action